# AutoFilter Complex Number Range

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to filter a worksheet and here's what I have so far:

```
Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1").AutoFilter Field:=12, 
    Criteria1:=Array("<34", "<>21", "<>22"),
    Operator:=xlAnd
```

`Field[12]` in the resulting rows must be:

- Less than **34**
- Not **21** or **22**

The problem is that `<>22` seems to be overriding `<34` and `<>21`. So is it possible to have the filter honor all of my criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$58").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("0", _
        "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "23", "24", "25", _
        "26", "27", "28", "29", "3", "30", "31", "32", "33", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), Operator _
        :=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: I was hoping for a shorter solution but this is where it's at.

Comment: Sorry Jeff......it can be made shorter by not using AutoFilter.....you could make a loop and examine each cell against the simple, intuitive, criteria in your post.....sometimes the restrictions of AutoFilter are not worth the couple of lines of VBA it saves.

Comment: When it comes to VBA I get tunnel vision, so I'm very grateful that you have provided me with a solution.